# How to store a URL using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, variables, url

```
<area data-nbmembre="Record" alt="R308" title="R308" href="#" onclick="openDialog('Record','documents/RCA-0025_0A.pdf#page=57')" shape="poly" coords="285,81,311,81,311,128,285,128" />
```

In JavaScript I want to store the URL:'documents/RCA-0025_0A.pdf#page=57'as shown above so I can change it in one location and have all the pages that have the same URL get updated as well.  Is this possible in JavaScript, if so, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Persist variables between page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads)

Comment: Look into WebRTC.